# Can you please give information on why the variable value is stored, but the size of the structure is still 0 bytes?

Tags: c, memory, structure, allocation

Why is the structure variable 'e' have no size, while its element is declared and initialized?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  struct e1
  {
    int a[0];
  };
  struct e1 e;
  e.a[0] = 2;
  printf ("%d\n", e.a[0]);
  printf ("%d", sizeof (e));
}
```

Output is
2
0

Comment: It doesn’t have an element. `e.a[0] = 2;` is undefined behaviour. Empty arrays and structs are also not standard C.

Answer (score 4):

You are over-running the buffer here:

```
e.a[0] = 2;
```

This invokes *undefined behavior*.

The program is not required to crash. In fact it may seem to run just fine, but you're trashing some other memory and the program could explode at any time.

To do this safely you must increase the size of your array to hold at least one element:

```
struct e1
{
    int a[1];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is **undefined behavior**. Your array has no elements, still you write one -- this is illegal and anything can happen. It's quite probable to **seem** working (might write some memory on the stack directly after your zero-sized struct, where maybe the next declared variable would be placed as well), but expect crashes soon...

**Something to remember now:** C never checks for errors like this, it just declares the behavior undefined. Be careful when programming in C.

As a side note: An array or struct of size zero doesn't even exist in standard C, so your compiler could reject this code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is **not valid C**. An array cannot have a zero as size.

Quoting `C11`, chapter

> If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: if it occurs in a
>   declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by `*`; **otherwise,
>   each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero.**

Considering your [compiler supports a zero-length array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) as the last element of a structure, you need to allocate memory first before you can actually make use of it.

Comment: But obviously the code compiled, because he's probably using GCC which [supports it as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Agree, but that does not change the fact.

Comment: Sure, but your answer doesn't explain the actual problem: that he's over-running the buffer. Why didn't you point out that his `main` isn't providing a prototype, or returning a value?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart regarding the second comment, any strictly conforming compiler would have rejected the code, so no question of running the binary. :)

Comment: Your quote is discussing variable-length arrays in [§6.7.6.2 ¶5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p5) and non-constant dimensions.  [C11 §6.7.26.2 Array declarators ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p1) is more relevant for fixed size arrays: _In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit
an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
have a value greater than zero._

Answer (score 0):

in your case it ivokes an undefined behavior. But very similar structs are used if you fave some data which has be stored in the struct but the size of it is unknown. But of course you need to allocate space for it

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    char string[];
}string;

string *String(void)
{
    string *s = malloc(sizeof(string));
    if(s) s -> size = 0;
    return s;
}

string *StringCopy(string *dest, const string *src)
{
    if(!src || !dest) return NULL;
    if(dest -> size < src -> size)
    {
        dest = realloc(dest, src -> size + sizeof(string));
        if(!dest) return NULL;
    }
    memcpy(dest -> string, src -> string, src -> size);
    dest -> size = src -> size;
    return dest;
}

string *StringCstringCopy(string *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t srcLength;
    if(!src || !dest) return NULL;

    srcLength = strlen(src);
    if(dest -> size < srcLength)
    {
        dest = realloc(dest, srcLength + sizeof(string));
        if(!dest) return NULL;
    }
    memcpy(dest -> string, src, srvLength);
    dest -> size = srcLength;
    return dest;
}


int main(void) {

    string *s = String();

    s = StringCstringCopy(s, "Hello");
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FAMs are a **completely** different thing than 0-sized arrays.

Comment: So I wrote - similar not identical. BTW zero length arrays are IMO 100% C valid (at least gcc valid) and widely used in many programs (especially network stacks) in the pre C99 era.

Comment: Although GCC without the `-pedantic` option accepts zero-size arrays, the standard says they’re forbidden. You should not put spaces around the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators. They bind very tightly indeed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `->` without the spaces looks horrible for me. Dot is a different story. Arrow without the spaces is just your liking and style  and is not the "absolute truth". You should write: `I do not like spaces around the arrow` instead of "You should not"

Comment: Remind me never to review your code. No one will be happy.  It is extremely unorthodox to use spaces around arrows; normally, one only sees it in beginner's code.  The first C book counselled against spaces around arrows and dots; you should follow the guidance of the deities who created C.